# How to get key value pair from a Pojo objects stored in ArrayList using java 7

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, pojo, classcastexception

I am passing a Json through Request obj and it is converted through gson and stored in ArrayList.

I want to get all the keys and its value to write in a file.

I tried this:

```
protected String add(ArrayList<User> input, HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response, User currentUser) throws APException {
 Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>)input.get(0); //to get all the keys of the first object.
      for (String key : map.keySet()){
        System.out.println("Key: " + key + " maps to value: " + map.get(key));
}
}
```

where User is a POJO class contains all the key fields and their getter/setter method

But I am getting : java.lang.ClassCastException: com.users.user.service.User cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Can anyone please suggest how can I get the key value pair from Array List. Like i have around 105 objects in the list and every objects has around 8 key- value pair.

Answer (score 0):

It's solution for 2 values stored in map object.

```
 Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
         
    map.put(input.get(0).getFirstName(), input.get(0).getGroupName());
```

If you want to store all values, I suggest to create map object like:

```
  Map<String,User> map = new HashMap<>();
```

where String value is in this example key.

```
map.put("yourKey", input.get(0));
```

Comment: So, like my list already contains key and value. Do i need to create another key with "userKey". Also like input.get (0) will have a key value pair of which i need value. Like i need to print the value corresponding to its key in an excel

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly. If your item in List already contains certain key value, why storing it in Map?  You can obtain  it like: 
`input.get(0).methodsOfPairGetKey`
`input.get(0).methodsOfPairGetValue`

Comment: I don't know if it's the most proper solution, but u can try something like this:
`String a; int x; [....]`
`for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++){`
`a = input.get(i).name; x = input.get(0).number; [....]}`